# Unexpected behavior with Cancellation token Dictionary in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, cancellation-token

I'm developing a WPF application in C# that interfaces with local and IP cameras, utilizing AForge.Video.DirectShow and CancellationTokenSource to handle tasks related to video capture. For tracking tasks for each camera, I use a Dictionary with camera index as key and CancellationTokenSource as value.

The problem I'm facing is that the Dictionary does not seem to be maintaining state as expected. I store a new CancellationTokenSource when a new task is created, but when I try to retrieve it with the same key later, it's not found in the Dictionary.

Here's the relevant section of my code. tokenSources is a Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource> that I use to store cancellation tokens for different tasks.

```
private async void LocalCamera_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBoxCamera = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    int cameraIndex = int.Parse(SourceComboBox.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""));
    int selectedItemIndex = comboBoxCamera.SelectedIndex;
    Image imageControl = comboBoxCamera.Tag as Image;

    Debug.WriteLine($"selectedItemIndex: {selectedItemIndex}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"cameraIndex: {cameraIndex}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"tokenSources contains cameraIndex: {tokenSources.ContainsKey(cameraIndex)}");

    // If selectedItemIndex is 0, cancel the current task if it's running
    if (selectedItemIndex == 0)
    {
        if (tokenSources.ContainsKey(cameraIndex))
        {
            var cts = tokenSources[cameraIndex];
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
            tokenSources.Remove(cameraIndex);
            Debug.WriteLine($"CancellationTokenSource for cameraIndex {cameraIndex} cancelled and removed.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If selectedItemIndex is greater than 0, start a new task
        var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSources[cameraIndex] = newCts;
        Debug.WriteLine($"New CancellationTokenSource created and stored for cameraIndex {cameraIndex}.");

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LocalCameraService.Instance.CaptureCameraCallback(selectedItemIndex - 1, SourceImageControl, newCts.Token), newCts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"tokenSources count after operations: {tokenSources.Count}");
}
```

The issue arises when I'm trying to interact with tokenSources:

When I store a new CancellationTokenSource for cameraIndex, the tokenSources Dictionary count increases to 1, as expected.
However, when I check tokenSources.ContainsKey(cameraIndex) for the same cameraIndex later, it returns False, which is not expected.
I have confirmed that cameraIndex is not changing unexpectedly, and I don't see anywhere in my code where tokenSources is being re-initialized. The program does not seem to maintain the state of the tokenSources Dictionary across different calls to the LocalCamera_ComboBox_SelectionChanged method.

I've tried to debug this issue by inserting various debug messages and using breakpoints, but I can't find any point where tokenSources is getting cleared or re-initialized.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something related to the lifecycle of WPF components, the use of Dictionaries, or asynchronous programming with tasks and cancellation tokens. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason that you prefer the verbose `Task.Factory.StartNew` over the simpler [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run)?

Comment: What is SourceComboBox? Anyway we cannot track the source of trouble from the code you posted.

Comment: Please post minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: What is SourceComboBox? either of combobox or custom type... if it is combobox.. why do you take index from name... probably need to get SourceComboBox.SelectedIndex. In other case it seems to your index will be always the same... and as result you remove  the same key from dictinanary.

Comment: Please debug your code and check if the keys involved are the same: is the index you use to store the CancellationTokenSource in the Dictionary the same as the index you use to read from the Dictionary? When you lookup the entry and the indices are the same does the Dictionary even has an entry? If not, your cancelable operation probably has already completed and removed the entry. You should check this. Better replace `Dictionary.ContainsKey` followed up by the indexer reference with a simple `Dictionary.TryGet` (will not help you with the issue).

Comment: Also your `else` block is commented with "If selectedItemIndex is greater than 0, start a new task". But this is wrong. the `else` block will also be executed when the selected index is `-1`. `-1` is a valid value that expresses that no item is selected. It will lead to unexpected behavior. You must explicitly check if the index is greater than `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you need to change this line of code:

```
int cameraIndex = int.Parse(SourceComboBox.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""));
```

to this:

```
int cameraIndex = int.Parse(comboBoxCamera.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""));
```

I would be using a different approach here.

```
private async void LocalCamera_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboboxes = new ComboBox[]
    {
        comboBox1, comboBox2,
        comboBox3, comboBox4,
    };

    System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBoxCamera = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    int cameraIndex = Array.IndexOf(comboboxes, comboBoxCamera);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code one more time it is obvious that you are using the wrong index to store the entry. Next time you must debug the values of the variables to verify that the key to store the entry in the `Dictionary` is the same as the key to obtain this entry.

You must use the `selectedItemIndex` to store the entry (and not the `cameraIndex`). Although it is not clear where `cameraIndex` comes from, it is clear that it represents the old index, the index or ID of the running cancellable operation. But you must register the new `CancellationTokenSource` with the new index i.e. the current index that is triggering the cancellable operation.

Maybe choosing better variable names would have saved you from spending precious time with this annoying and avoidable error.
For example `previousCameraIndex` or `cameraIndexOfTaskToCancel` (instead of cameraIndex) and `currentCameraIndex` or `cameraIndexOfTaskToStart` (instead of selectedCameraIndex). Now it would be more difficult for you to mix them up, because of the semantics when reading the code.

Also using `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToke)` is the absolute equivalent of `StartNew(Action, CancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions, TaskScheduler)` where `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`and `TaskScheduler.Default` (the way you configured it) - only more compact and simpler. That's why `Task.Run` was introduced.

```cs
var comboBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
int cameraIndexOfTaskToCancel = int.Parse(SourceComboBox.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""));
int cameraIndexOfTaskToStart = comboBoxCamera.SelectedIndex;

if (cameraIndexOfTaskToStart == 0  
  && tokenSources.TryGetValue(cameraIndexOfTaskToCancel, out CancellationTokenSource cts))
{
  cts.Cancel();
  cts.Dispose();
  _ = tokenSources.Remove(cameraIndexOfTaskToCancel);
  Debug.WriteLine($"CancellationTokenSource for cameraIndex {cameraIndex} cancelled and removed.");
}
else if (cameraIndexOfTaskToStart > 0)  // Add explicit 'index > 0' check to avoid bugs when index is '-1'
{
  var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  tokenSources[cameraIndexOfTaskToStart] = newCts;
  Debug.WriteLine($"New CancellationTokenSource created and stored for cameraIndex {selectedItemIndex}.");

  // For your scenario better use Task.Run
  await Task.Run(
    () => LocalCameraService.Instance.CaptureCameraCallback(
      cameraIndexOfTaskToStart - 1, 
      SourceImageControl, 
      newCts.Token), 
    newCts.Token);
}
```